# Can I start an unpublished Nintex workflow?

Tags: nintex-workflow

I am building a Nintex workflow for a SharePoint 2013 list. I am making continuous changes, and I quickly run up the number of versions. Is there a way to (a) start an unpublished workflow as I am the only one who needs to run it, or (b) to unpublish a workflow so I have version 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, whatever and then publish it as 2.0 when it is ready to show to someone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. The entire point of publishing a workflow is to make it available to run.
What you could do is publish it under another name for as long as you are testing. Once you confirm it's working as you intended, publish it under the initial name and overwrite the 'public' version.

Concerning the version numbers, every time you save the workflow a minor version is created (the number behind the dot). Everytime you publish it, a major version is created (the number before the dot)

If you want to revert to an older version, you can do this by opening an older version. On the ribbon, click the open button and tick the checkbox to display previous versions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did figure that out. But you can't revert back to an older version. What I would LIKE to do is to unpublish, then work on a prerelease version. So I publish as 2.0, then unpublish back to 1.5, then save 1.6 and test, save 1.7 and test, etc. then go live for everyone else with a new published 2.0. That's how other SharePoint libraries work. But Nintex doesn't support that.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean you can't revert to an older version?

In the ribbon of the workflow, click Open. That should give you the option to revert to any previous versions.

[image: Nintex Workflow Open Screen]

Click on any version you want, click Select in its ribbon, and that will load the previous version. You can republish it if you'd like, and it'll just make a copy of it to be the latest version number.